Is 2W10 bridge rectifier required in wiring harness for my utility vehicle (DC DC supply)?
I am a civil engineer by profession but always have done my electrical wiring in my utility vehicle and all has been working good.
Okay so I got this wiring harness for 7" driving light and and as I was testing it I think I blown the 2W10 bridge rectifier so I took the rectifier off the circuit and connected the wires from relay directly to the piggy back adapter H4 for high beam wiring connection..
The lights are working fine, my question is do I really need that rectifier or the direct connection will be fine?

What exactly is a ute?

it is utility vehicle.. got a Toyota land cruiser

The rectifier is there to simplify installation
and possibly to absorb back emf from the relay (or the relay may already have a built-in diode that does that)
